# How to execute a batch file each time a user logins?

Tags: batch-file, login-script, xcopy

I've written a batch script which copies of some files in the CommonAppData folder (C:\ProgramData) to the logged in User's Local AppData. What I would like to do is to execute this script for every user every time they login. I found many articles talking about the execution of batch files on startup but I would like to know how to do the same on each login.

I've a written a batch file and copied it in :

> C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Logon

But it does not seem to be working.

Comment: please let me know why should there be a downvote?

Comment: Probably because it wasn't really clear what you were asking. And because it was a pretty "basic" question, although it's perfectly legitimate one in my opinion. @ptman has your answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want [Logon scripts](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/556007)

Comment: how do you write one? what language is it?

Comment: I have written a sample vbs script to copy a file from D:\ to C:\, where should I save the file so that it executes in login?

Answer (score 1):

Put your batch/script file in:
C:\windows\system32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Logon
Note: no spaces in the filename use _ or - instead
ie: map_drive.bat or map-drive.bat    not: map drive.bat

Once complete open gpedit.msc
Select user configuration->windows settings->scripts
Double click on Logon
Select add and browse to your batch/script file
Make sure you click "Apply" or your changes will not be saved.

Answer (score 0):

In case it is needed at home or something small you could put it in the Startup folder of the user, it get executed each time the user enters the system.

It is simple, but I like to keep things like that.

Comment: where is that folder located in the computer?

Comment: Windows 7 and Vista

c:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Windows XP

c:\Documents and Settings\[username]\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Comment: but then it would be executed only when the system boots. My requirement is to execute on user login